# comparing 2 arrays with _.difference

Tags: javascript, lodash

Im using lodash with some calculations, but there is a function that isnt working has i expected, im using for example 'difference'.

His usage is:

```
_.difference([2, 1], [2, 3]);
output: [1]
```

But when i apply to my arrays:

```
_.difference([5111471, 5111513], [5111471,5111505,5111513]);
output:[]
```

Instead of giving me [5111505], is giving me a empty array.

Comment: For that you need to provide the second argument as first `_.difference( [5111471,5111505,5111513],[5111471, 5111513]);`

Comment: Is the data always sorted?

Answer (score 1):

`_.difference` returns elements of the first array not present in the second one. There are no such elements in your example, hence the empty result. If you want a [symmetric difference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference) (that is, elements that are present in the first array or the second, but not in both), you can do something like

```
diff = _.union(_.difference(a, b), _.difference(b, a))
```

Answer (score 0):

_.difference doesn't actually return the difference between two arrays, but instead  returns the first array minus the second. So to return [5111505] you need to do:

```
_.difference([5111471,5111505,5111513],[5111471, 5111513]);
```

See documentation for more info:
https://lodash.com/docs/4.15.0#difference